# Looping through an array of integers efficiently

Tags: c#

**Test Cases**

**Case 1**
Given ranks[3,4,3,0,2,2,3,0,0], your function should return 5, because :

- Three soldiers of rank 3 (ranks[0], ranks[2], ranks[6]) may report to a soldier of rank 4 (ranks[1])
- Two soldiers of rank 2 may report to any soldier of rank 3

**Case 2**
Given ranks[4,2,0], your function should return 0.

**Case 3**
Given ranks[4,4,3,3,1,0], your function should return 3, because :

- A soldier of rank 0 can report to a soldier of rank 1
- Two soldiers of rank 3 can report to any soldier of rank 4

**Task**
Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions :

- N is an integer within the range [2.. 100,000]
- Each element of array ranks is an integer within the range [0.. 1,000,000,000]

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var rand = new Random();
            var ranks = new int[][]
            {
                new int[]{ 3, 4, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0}, // 5
                new int[]{ 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1 }, // 8
                new int[]{4 , 2, 0}, // 0
                new int[]{4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 0}, // 3
                new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}, // 4
                new int[]{0,2,4}, // 0
                new int[]{1,1,1,1,1,1, 3,2, 2, 1}, // 9
         //       Enumerable.Range(1,100000).ToList().Select(a => rand.Next(1000000000)).ToArray()
            };

            var solver = new Solution();

            foreach (var test in ranks)
            {
                var result = solver.solution(test);
                Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Solution
    {
        public int solution(int[] ranks)
        {
            int count = 0;

            // First ranks traversal
            for (int x = 0; x < ranks.Length; x++)
            {
                foreach(int yrank in ranks)
                {
                    if (ranks[x] == yrank) continue;

                    if (ranks[x] + 1 == yrank)
                    {
                        // if x+1 is present
                        count += 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

My solution is working for simple test cases but it's not at all an efficient solution. I'm sure I can simplify greatly the problem and not having two loops which give us a time complexity of at least O(n^2). I'm sure this problem can be simplified up to a time complexity of O(logN) or maybe something better but I can't see how...
I thought of sorting the ranks array first but it's not more efficient.

***Could you please give me some help on this kind of problem or tell me what I did wrong in my approach ?
Thank you.

---

Comment: Is it a kata from CodeWars.com :D?

Comment: Actually I don't know if that's the case at all, it's a problem that was presented to me during an interview and I still felt horrible because I coundn't get myself to come up with a better solution that the one I mentionned before.

Answer (score 2):

I took your model and migrated it to a [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) project:

Below is the code.

Solution1 is a copy of yours.
Solution2 is an alternative.
Solution3 is copied from a poster who posted an answer before me.

You can add as many solutions as you like and see how they perform.

Spoiler, here are the results:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Rank | Gen0 | Gen1 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Solution3 | 1.659 ms | 0.0259 ms | 0.0217 ms | 1 | 21.4844 | 1.9531 | 97473 B |
| Solution2 | 10.284 ms | 0.1994 ms | 0.2134 ms | 2 | - | - | 8 B |
| Solution1 | 68.283 ms | 0.6395 ms | 0.6281 ms | 3 | - | - | 120 B |

As you can see, Solution2 is much faster with less resource allocation and Solution3 is 5X faster still, but with more memory allocation and a bit of garbage collection (Gen0 and Gen1).

I'll leave it to you to judge speed vs. memory allocation, but a benchmarking tool like this one will help you best judge different ideas if the comparisons are fair.

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
[Orderer(SummaryOrderPolicy.FastestToSlowest)]
[RankColumn]
public class ListTraversal
{
    //private static int[][] data = Array.Empty<int[]>();
    private static int[] ranks = Array.Empty<int>();

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var rand = new Random();

        //ranks = new int[] { 3, 4, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0 }; // 5;

        ranks = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000).ToList().Select(a => rand.Next(0, 1000)).ToArray();

        //    data = new int[][] {
        //       new int[]{ 3, 4, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0}, // 5
        //       new int[]{ 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1 }, // 8
        //       new int[]{4 , 2, 0}, // 0
        //       new int[]{4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 0}, // 3
        //       new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}, // 4
        //       new int[]{0,2,4}, // 0
        //       new int[]{1,1,1,1,1,1, 3,2, 2, 1}, // 9
        ////       Enumerable.Range(1,100000).ToList().Select(a => rand.Next(1000000000)).ToArray()
        //};

    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Solution1()
    {
        int count = 0;

        // First ranks traversal
        for (int x = 0; x < ranks.Length; x++)
        {
            foreach (int yrank in ranks)
            {
                if (ranks[x] == yrank) continue;

                if (ranks[x] + 1 == yrank)
                {
                    // if x+1 is present
                    count += 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Solution2()
    {
        int count = 0;

        ReadOnlySpan<int> copy = new ReadOnlySpan<int>(ranks);

        // First ranks traversal
        for (int x = 0; x < ranks.Length; x++)
        {
            count += (copy.Contains(ranks[x] + 1))
                ? 1
                : 0;
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Solution3()
    {
        var count = 0;

        var map = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        foreach (var rank in ranks)
            map[rank] = map.ContainsKey(rank) ? map[rank] + 1 : 1;

        var sorted = map.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Count - 1; i++)
            if (sorted[i].Key + 1 == sorted[i + 1].Key)
                count += sorted[i].Value;
    }
}
```

My `Program.cs` is simply:

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

BenchmarkRunner.Run<ListTraversal>();
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for taking the time to teach me this tool, BenchmarkDotNet and taking the time to come up with a better solution too, that's just awesome ! I understand the solution and it's so much better than what I could come up. I made harder on myself the problem than what it really was I think..

Comment: I just have one question about Solution 2 please. Why are you using a ReadOnlySpan as copy of ranks array and not ranks itself ? 
I don't understand why I used directly the ContainsKey method :/

Comment: @GrahamSchwardt The ReadOnlySpan is pretty efficient, but I didn’t choose it for any special reason. I might have had been thinking I needed a copy; but I think you’re right that I could have used ranks instead.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is O(nlogn) in the worst case scenario. An average complexity have to be better, because I sort unique ranks not all ranks

```cs
public int solution(int[] ranks)
{
    var count = 0;

    var map = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    foreach (var rank in ranks)
        map[rank] = map.ContainsKey(rank) ? map[rank] + 1 : 1;

    var sorted = map.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Count - 1; i++)
        if (sorted[i].Key + 1 == sorted[i + 1].Key)
            count += sorted[i].Value;

    return count;
}
```

UPDATE: new version has O(n) complexity! (but it can be hard to understand :)).

```cs
public int solution1(int[] ranks)
{
    var count = 0;

    var map = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    // O(n)
    foreach (var rank in ranks)
    {
        if (!map.ContainsKey(rank))
            map[rank] = -2;
        else
        {
            var sign = map[rank] >= 0 ? 1 : -1;

            map[rank] = map[rank] + 1 * sign;
        }

        if (!map.ContainsKey(rank - 1))
            map[rank - 1] = 1;
        else
            map[rank - 1] = Math.Abs(map[rank - 1]);
    }

    foreach (var item in map)
        if(item.Value > 1)
            count += item.Value - 1;

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for taking the time to come up with a better solution and taking the time to explain it ! I really appreciate it. I don't know why I didn't had the idea to sort the array at the beginning..